# Find and count specific pairs

Tags: algorithm

- We have Array of N real numbers ( lets say its double type ).
- each number in array
- array is sorted and growing
- Pairs are like (P, Q)
- 0 <= P < N
- Q > P
- pair is counted if A[P] * A[Q] > A[P] + A[Q]
- desired complexity is O(N)
- return pair count

this is codility task to do. I couldn't go past modified O[(n^2)/2] complexity , maybe shorter for specific data sets, and its really annoying me... Anybody have idea how to get closer to O(N)?

My idea was to find first pair that is correct, and every next will be correct too. Worst case scenario will be O[(n^2)/2] optimistic something like 2n or 3n.

edit: my mistake twalberg, i already corrected complexity

Comment: What is the point of a coding challenge when you just ask for the solution?

Comment: i already did it. its not challenge, its coding task.

Comment: You missed the most important information - that the array is sorted.

Comment: You are aware that `O(logN) < O(N)`, aren't you? If you've come up with a valid `O(logN)` solution, then you have exceeded the `O(N)` expectation... Of course, I'm not necessarily convinced you have come up with an `O(logN)` solution...